# Include xml prolog in web request

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, web-services, wsdl

I've added a Service Reference for a third-party web service to my project.  When i send a request to a webservice using the generated method, the request fails saying that it is missing the XML prolog.

How can I add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

to the begining of the request before sending it?

This is a C# web application.

Comment: Since it's a 3rd party web-service, your followup question is interesting, but probably not terribly relevant for Adam.

Comment: Eric, it's extremely relevant. The answer will be "because the service doesn't follow XML standards". XML works so well because 95% or more of apps follow the standards. What happens when that number drops to 80%? XML may become useless.

Comment: @Adam: What would you do if this third-party web service crashed, or produced  bad data? It would be a bug, and you'd require them to fix the bug. Failing to properly parse XML is a bug. You must require them to fix it.

Comment: @John: I see now that it is a bug in the third-party web service, and they are working on a fix. However, in the meanwhile, is there anything I can do to workaround this bug?

Comment: @Adam: if the third-party needs help fixing this bug quickly, recommend they ask for help on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd-party has fixed the webservice. Problem solved.